# .htaccess fine on localhost, 500 internal server error on webserver

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to redirect show files in folder/dist when accessing folder/ in a webapp using .htaccess.
This works as desired on localhost (xampp apache) but when pushed to the server (AWS Elastic Beanstalk Apache) I get a **error code 500 Internal Server Error**.

I've created the webapp using the [Yeoman Angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) and it's running the webapp on an Apache server. The project is in a subfolder of the whole site (http://url.com/pages/webapp). Grunt creates the application in the *dist* folder and I this content is what I want the visitor to see when accessing the root of the webapp.
Basically I want to redirect/rewrite http://url.com/pages/webapp/ to http://url.com/pages/webapp/dist/

Im trying to accomplish this with a .htaccess that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ dist/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^dist/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dist/$1
```

The *exact same* htaccess-content is used in other projects on the same server and they work fine. Only projects created with this generator has this issue.

Is the problem in my htacceess-file, other part of webapp or Elastic Beanstalk...?

I have tried adding `AllowOverride All` (root directory) and `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` to */etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf* but it didn't work.
I also didn't find anything interesting in error_log

I realize the problem is probably hard to solve with the information provided but I am hoping someone else has had a similar issue. 
Thanks

Comment: There must be something related to 500 in your Apache error.log

Comment: Maybe this? "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error."

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ dist/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dist/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dist/$1 [L]
```

Note leading `/` before `dist` in `RewriteCond`.